# Ошибка при создании sequence: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create sequence city_eremin_mp302_sequence
start with (select max(n_street) from street)
```

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Почему не работает запрос, и что нужно исправить, чтобы он заработал?

Нужно начать последовательность с самого большого значения поля `n_street` в таблице `street`, где `n_street` первичный ключ.

Comment: При возникновении ошибок СУБД обычно пишет из-за чего они произошли.

Comment: `create sequence` является оператором DDL, в нем нельзя использовать никакие операторы DML, в том числе и подзапрос `select`. Необходимо указать число явно

Answer (score 2):

Не работает потому, что после [`START WITH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html) ожидается число. Кроме того, надо наращивать последнее значение, иначе будет нарушение уникальности первичного ключа.

Так будет работать:

```
create table street as select 10 n_street from dual
/
set verify off
col val new_value maxn val
select max (n_street)+1 val from street
/
create sequence city_seq start with &val nocycle nocache
/
insert into street
    select city_seq.nextval from dual
/
select * from street;

1 row inserted.


  N_STREET
----------
        10
        11
```